# Python scrolling through an overflow scroll box on your instagram follower's list?

Tags: python

Practicing web scraping through selenium by parsing user's profiles through instagram. When I click on my follower's page, a dialog box appears and I need it to scroll down and through the list. My current code works but the issue is that it scrolls too quickly and because of that instagram locks it out from viewing more profiles. Is there any way to lower the scroll speed here or make it mimic a human scrolling the page?

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda d: d.find_element_by_css_selector('div[role="dialog"]'))

driver.execute_script('''
    var fDialog = document.querySelector('div[role="dialog"] .isgrP');
    fDialog.scrollTop = fDialog.scrollHeight
''')
```

Comment: Looks like a JavaScript question to me. You can probably slowly increment `fDialog.scrollTop` in a loop until it reaches `fDialog.scrollHeight`

Comment: What would be the code that goes inside the loop? I am just not sure what code to put within a loop to make the scrolling more human-like.

Comment: I've answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59010109/1911755